# How to correct line chart starting point in Jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

As you can seen from the image, the line in this chart starts from 2 and not 1. Can anyone help me sort this out? What should I change to make it start from 1?[image]

```
from numpy.random import randint

df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],list(randint(400,500,11)),randint(400,500,11)]).T
df1.columns=['CustomerS','value1','value2']
df1=df1.set_index('CustomerS')
df2=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],randint(0,10,11)]).T
df2.columns=['CustomerS','value1']
df2=df2.set_index('CustomerS')
ax=df1.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
ax2=ax.twinx()

df2.plot(kind='line', color='r',ax= ax2)
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Grayrigel No, not yet :(

Comment: I have added an answer. Please upvote and accept if helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from numpy.random import randint
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],list(randint(400,500,11)),randint(400,500,11)]).T
df1.columns=['CustomerS','value1','value2']
#df1=df1.set_index('CustomerS')
df2=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],randint(0,10,11)]).T
df2.columns=['CustomerS','value1']
#df2=df2.set_index('CustomerS')

df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='CustomerS') #merging two dataframes
df3.columns = ['CustomerS','value1','value2','value3']
df3.iloc[:,:-1].plot.bar(x='CustomerS',stacked=True)

df3.iloc[:,-1].plot(x='CustomerS',secondary_y=True, color='r')
plt.legend(loc=2)
```

**Output**:
[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. The tradition is to accept and upvote.